# Attempting to read a txt into dataframe, with '|' as separator, but pd keeps on skipping lines

Tags: pandas, csv, text

I am trying to import a messy text file (formatted from raw html **scraper** output) into pd dataframe, for better orientation and further processing. The file contains '|' as separators between values in one column, and I can't figure out where my mistake is as there should be four fields per column, as based on number of separators included.

Here providing couple of text file lines, where each of the '|' acts as a delimiter behind company name, address, type and activity. I have tried replacing the delimiter with a different character, or setting up a regex condition in case '|' is somehow a special character, but to no avail.

```
'3sun Group' '|'
 '3 Sun House Boundary Road, Southtown, Great Yarmouth, Norfolk, NR31 0FB'
 '|' 'Private limited Company' '|' '71129 - Other engineering activities'
'Abacus' '|'
 '100 Cedarwood Crockford Lane, Chineham Business Park, Chineham, Basingstoke, Hampshire, England, RG24 8WD'
 '|' 'Private limited Company' '|'
 '66220 - Activities of insurance agents and brokers'
'Accsys Group' '|'
 'Lea Cottage Old Harrowden Road, Harrowden, Bedford, United Kingdom, MK42 0TB'
 '|' '27 November 2018' '|'
 '72110 - Research and experimental development on biotechnology'
'Acro' '|' '291 Green Lanes, London, England, N13 4XS' '|'
 'Private limited Company' '|' '46410 - Wholesale of textiles'
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('creg.txt', sep='|', names=["Company", "Address", "Type", "Industry"])

print (df)
```

Expected result is a dataframe containing entries as such:

```
Company
'3sun Group' '
Address 
'
 '3 Sun House Boundary Road, Southtown, Great Yarmouth, Norfolk, NR31 0FB'
 '
Type
' 'Private limited Company' 
Industry
' '71129 - Other engineering activities'
```

Current results look like this:

```
                                          Company  \
0                                       '3sun Group' '   
1     '3 Sun House Boundary Road, Southtown, Great ...   
2                                                    '   
3                                           'Abacus' '   
4     '100 Cedarwood Crockford Lane, Chineham Busin...   
5                                                    '   
6     '66220 - Activities of insurance agents and b...   
7                                     'Accsys Group' '   
8     'Lea Cottage Old Harrowden Road, Harrowden, B...   
9                                                    '   
  Address  \
0                                                    '   
1                                                  NaN   
2                        ' 'Private limited Company' '   
3                                                    '   
4                                                  NaN   
5                        ' 'Private limited Company' '   
6                                                  NaN   
    Type Industry  
0                                         NaN      NaN  
1                                         NaN      NaN  
2    ' '71129 - Other engineering activities'      NaN  
3                                         NaN      NaN  
4                                         NaN      NaN  
5                                           '      NaN  
6                                         NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re.sub()` to perform some preliminary cleanup of your .txt file and then use `io.StringIO()` to pass this string to `pd.read_csv()` as the constructor for your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import re, io

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = re.sub(r'\s+\|\s+', ';', re.sub(r'\'', '', f.read()))

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep=r';', names=["Company", "Address", "Type", "Industry"], engine='python')
```

Outputs:

```
        Company                                            Address  \
0    3sun Group  3 Sun House Boundary Road, Southtown, Great Ya...   
1        Abacus  100 Cedarwood Crockford Lane, Chineham Busines...   
2  Accsys Group  Lea Cottage Old Harrowden Road, Harrowden, Bed...   
3          Acro          291 Green Lanes, London, England, N13 4XS   

                      Type                                           Industry  
0  Private limited Company               71129 - Other engineering activities  
1  Private limited Company  66220 - Activities of insurance agents and bro...  
2         27 November 2018  72110 - Research and experimental development ...  
3  Private limited Company                      46410 - Wholesale of textiles
```

Comment: The answer resolved my question for everything except the first entry, which was somehow ommited and skipped for the whole df: (e.g. company = 3 Sun House Boundary Road etc..., Address = Private limited, Type = Other engineering, Industry = NaN 
I can rewrite that one manually, but it would be neat to not have it that way
if you know how this can be helped it would be very appreciated

Comment: You may want to pass `header=False` as an argument to `pd.read_csv()`